# How to do run time calibration for MPU9250?

Tags: arduino-uno, mpu6050

Does anyone know how to do the run time calibration for MPU9250 ?

Comment: By that you mean finding the calibration matrix for each sensor? Like offsets, gains, hard iron corrections?

Answer (score 2):

I used [this script](http://wired.chillibasket.com/2015/01/calibrating-mpu6050/) to calibrate the MPU6050, which is the same as the MPU9250 minus the digital compass. [This guide](https://github.com/kriswiner/MPU-6050/wiki/Simple-and-Effective-Magnetometer-Calibration) explains how to calibrate the MPU9250's magnetometer.